# Linking Static GLFW and OpenGL on a Mac with CMake

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, cmake

I am trying to test out glfw3 on a mac. I am not able to build a simple project because I am not able to link against OpenGL.

**Directory Structure**

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── OpenGL
│   ├── Application.cpp
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── dependencies
│       └── GLFW
│           ├── include
│           │   └── GLFW
│           │       ├── glfw3.h
│           │       └── glfw3native.h
│           ├── lib
│           │   └── libglfw3.a
│           └── src
└── bin
```

**CMakeList.txt**

Top Level CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_subdirectory(OpenGL)
```

Nested CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(OpenGL)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

add_executable(OpenGL Application.cpp)

target_include_directories(OpenGL PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/GLFW/include)
target_link_libraries(OpenGL ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a)
```

**Applicatin.cpp (Taken Directly from glfw.org [here](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); <-- this line throws an error

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

**Error Message**

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '../OpenGL/dependencies/GLFW/include/lib/libglfw3.a', needed by '../bin/OpenGL'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 50%] Building CXX object OpenGL/CMakeFiles/OpenGL.dir/Application.cpp.o
/Users/dblock/CLionProjects/OpenGL/OpenGL/Application.cpp:27:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT'
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [OpenGL/CMakeFiles/OpenGL.dir/build.make:63: OpenGL/CMakeFiles/OpenGL.dir/Application.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: OpenGL/CMakeFiles/OpenGL.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:98: OpenGL/CMakeFiles/OpenGL.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: OpenGL] Error 2
```

My IDE (CLion) says the following

```
Can't resolve variable 'glClear'
Can't resolve variable 'GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT'
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

**Edit**

I added #import  and now I am getting a new error

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/bin/cmake --build /Users/dblock/CLionProjects/OpenGL/cmake-build-debug --target OpenGL -- -j 4
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '../OpenGL/dependencies/GLFW/include/lib/libglfw3.a', needed by '../bin/OpenGL'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: OpenGL/CMakeFiles/OpenGL.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:98: OpenGL/CMakeFiles/OpenGL.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:118: OpenGL] Error 2
```

**Solution**

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h> //<-- add this included to main.cpp fixed my issue
```

Comment: There is no file `OpenGL/dependencies/GLFW/include/lib/libglfw3.a` in your project. You have `OpenGL/dependencies/GLFW/lib/libglfw3.a` one. BTW, why use `find_package(OpenGL)` and do not use its results?

Comment: @Tsyvarev the answer to that Is I am new to both c++ and CMake. I am making rookie mistakes that I am not noticing. Please elaborate on how to correct my mistakes.

Comment: If you're really using `#import` rather than `#include` to include the OpenGL header, then that is certainly incorrect.

Comment: @SeanBurton Id rather do it correctly. I came across that as a possibly solution so I tried it. I am removing it now please advise on the correct way to link OpenGL

Comment: You need to use a GL loader eg [glad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad)

Comment: @Asaq As I am new to both c++ and CMake please explain further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDE clearly tells that no declaration were found for `glClear` and `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`

Since OpenGL is a standard/specification it is up to the driver manufacturer to implement the specification to a driver that the specific graphics card supports. Since there are many different versions of OpenGL drivers, the location of most of its functions is not known at compile-time and needs to be queried at run-time. It is then the task of the developer to retrieve the location of the functions he/she needs and store them in function pointers for later use.

You need header where OpenGL functions declared and loader that loads these functions. Thankfully, there are libraries for this purpose as well where GLAD is a popular and up-to-date library.

Generate GLAD loader/header - http://glad.dav1d.de.

Update directory Structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── OpenGL
│   ├── Application.cpp
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── glad.c
│   └── dependencies
│       ├── GLFW
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── glad
│       │   └── glad.h
│       └── KHR
│           └── khrplatform.h
└── bin
```

Update Nested CMakeList.txt:

```
set(SOURCES Application.cpp glad.c)
add_executable(OpenGL ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(OpenGL PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies)
```

Update Applicatin.cpp:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
...

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
{ 
  // Failed to create GLFW window
  glfwTerminate();
  return -1;
}
// now you can use OpenGL functions
```

More info in GLAD [github](http://glad.dav1d.de), complete [example](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad/blob/master/example/c%2B%2B/hellowindow2.cpp). Excellent OpenGL [tutorials](https://learnopengl.com).

Comment: Thank you for the information. It was very helpful because its the next step in what I am trying to do. However if anyone is experiencing my issue. The following import fixed my issue. #include <OpenGL/gl.h>

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the relative path the cmake is resolving to is incorrect (doesn't exist).
I'd suggest you install glfw3 from [HomeBrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) like this:

```
brew install --static glfw3
```

And specify the absolute path of glfw3 as "/usr/local/lib"

Comment: thanks you made me realize I botched the path. Copy and paste sometimes gets the best of me. I will consider install with brew an option. However since I corrected the path I am getting a new error. Any idea what my new mistake it?